# How do you update a Set on DynamoDB using JavaScript document client?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add some items to a DynamoDB set. This worked fine with the original JavaScript SDK, but not with the new DocumentClient, using the createSet() function. Here's my code:

```
'use strict';

let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
                region: 'us-east-2',
                accessKeyId: 'AKIAJWIR35J4YZF4RQVQ',
                secretAccessKey: 'xxxx'
            });

var params = {
    TableName : 'qa_Web_Application',
    Key: {'Application_ID': '78f27a00-11f6-49cc-9adb-ae0795cf79d4'},
    UpdateExpression : 'ADD #idList :newIds',
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
      '#idList' : 'ids'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
      ':newIds' : docClient.createSet([1,2])
    }
};

console.log( params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":newIds"] );

docClient.update(params, function(err,data) {
    if( err !== null ) {
        console.log( err, err.stack );
    } else {
        console.log ( data );
    }
});
```

Here's the output:

```
constructor {values: Array(2), type: "Number"}
Error: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: MAP
```

I've seen this same question here ([How do you update a Set on DynamoDB using JavaScript document client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521994/how-do-you-update-a-set-on-dynamodb-using-javascript-document-client)), but that's what I'm basing this code example on, and it fails.

Comment: I found the problem - using the minified AWS JavaScript library does not work. The full size version works, but it is unfortunately 3.6 megabytes, making this basically unusable.

Comment: Hi Jesse, did you ever find a resolution on this? And how did you consume the non-minified AWS SDK, did you do that via npm?

Comment: They released an updated minified version within a day or two of me reporting this issue to them; I don't remember what the version number was, but if you download the latest version it should work.

Comment: To download the non-minified version, I used their SDK JavaScript builder tool. I had to manually view the HTM source to switch between minified and non-minified because of a CSS issue.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, much appreciated. I actually realised my issue was that I had a List of Strings, rather than a String Set